# Amazon S3 bucket policy, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I used the [Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to create a simple rule for my bucket; the rules should allow the following intended effect:

- root access
- limit access to given IAM user
- allow read-only access to everyone

To this purpose I wrote the following rule, but somethng didnt work as expected, and in particular, I have totally lost access to the bucket elements, was getting "Access Denied" in all cases, root included:

[image]

**edit**: with @jarmod answer I was able to set the intended functionality, however it trigger a warning, about the bucket being public, I do not see the difference respect having no policy, the bucket is still publicly accessible for read-only. What is the difference?

[image]

Comment: Explicit deny > explicit allow > implicit deny. Your 1st and 2nd statements should be removed and you are missing a statement that allows "read-only access to everyone".

Comment: @jarmod so root is implicit allowed? I was reading [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/) and in the example they set `deny *` for everyone else and specified to allow the root access.

Comment: You can't have a deny * and an allow x because the deny * is explicit and trumps every allow. Root has implicit access to everything, but you should not be using root credentials for anything (see AWS best practices for root user).

Comment: The deny example in the guide you're referring to, if I'm reading the correct one, has a conditional policy statement, denying all access except to a specific role and the root user. You would use this if you specifically want to override IAM-level permissions for an S3 bucket (so you could deny access to an IAM user who actually did have permissions for the bucket, for example). That's not what you're trying to do, as far as I can determine, so that policy is not relevant.

Comment: @jarmod yes sir! as per my second dot in the list, I'm trying to **limit access to given IAM user**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could do this as follows:

1. for all users, allow action s3:GetObject
2. for all users except root and your specific IAM user, deny all actions except s3:GetObject

You could do this with a policy something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "NotAction": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "iam-userid-here",
                        "root-userid-here"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To get `iam-userid-here`, run `aws iam list-users` and retrieve the UserId for the IAM user.

Similarly, to get `root-userid-here`, simply retrieve the account number from the Arn of the previous `aws iam list-users` output. The root account userId *is* the AWS account number.

The IAM user indicated by `iam-userid-here` could then have an IAM policy allowing S3 access.

Comment: this is partially working, by allowing read-only to everyone I meant also not logged in users, like public guests. In the bucket I upload files I want to share providing the URL, while my root and IAM user can access the bucket, public visitors are denied access to the file.

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment means. Are you saying that you want to provide public read access to the objects but not allow IAM users (other than the one specific user) to read them? If so, why? Giving public read access surely means everyone.

Comment: I missread the code you shared, using the tool I could not set `NotAction` and was not working initially. I wanted to make a shared folder to send files, a IAM user is an app that uploads the files. I'm just wondering why it marks the bucket as public, while it was accessible also without the policy.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're referring to how the AWS S3 console highlights the fact that the bucket is public. The bucket contents would not have been accessible publicly without some form of policy allowing that.

Comment: I just tested it by removing the policy, logged out of amazon I was able to show the file content (image) inside the bucket. How is it possible?

Comment: If you're saying that you can visit https://s3.amazonaws.com/yourbucket/yourkey and the browser successfully downloads or shows your file then the S3 object is public. It's public because either you have a bucket policy making it public or you have object-level ACLs making it public.